# glVertexAttrib4f not working in OS X, but works fine in iOS?

Tags: macos, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to port a simple OpenGL ES 2.0 renderer I made for iOS to OS X desktop and I'm running into into a 'nothing rendering' problem, and I don't get any errors reported so I'm at a loss what to do. So far I've narrowed the problem down to a call I make to `glVertexAttrib4f`, which is only working in OS X. Can anyone take a look at the following code and see why the call to `glVertexAttrib4f` doesn't work on desktop?:

```
void Renderer::drawTest()
{
    gl::clear( mBackgroundColor );

    static Vec2f vertices[3] = { Vec2f( 0, 0 ), Vec2f( 0.5, 1 ), Vec2f( 1, 0 ) };
    static int indices[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };

    mShader.bind();

    glEnableVertexAttribArray( mAttributes.position );
    glVertexAttribPointer( mAttributes.position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vertices[0] );

#ifdef USING_GENERIC_ARRAY_POINTER
    // works in iOS /w ES2 and OSX:
    static Color colors[3] = { Color( 0, 0, 1 ), Color( 0, 0, 1 ), Color( 0, 0, 1 ) };
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( mAttributes.color );
    glVertexAttribPointer( mAttributes.color, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &colors[0] );
#else // using generic attribute
    // works in iOS, but doesn't work in OSX ?:
    glVertexAttrib4f( mAttributes.color, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
#endif

    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &indices[0] );

    errorCheck(); // calls glGetError, which always returns GL_NO_ERROR
}
```

note: this is example code that I stripped out of something much more complex, please forgive me for not making it more complete.

versions:
desktop OS X is 2.1 ATI-7.18.18
iPhone simulator is OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE

Comment: Define "works". What exactly is it that this function is supposed to do? Do you remove the color array when you try to call `glVertexAttrib4f`?

Comment: By works I mean it shows a triangle in the upper right corner of the screen, in both iOS and OS X.  Yes, I am only doing  the `glVertexAttribPointer` method or `glVertexAttrib4f` method, not both. I'll try to edit the code so it is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why drawing wasn't happening while calling `glVertexAttrib4f` was that `mAttributes.color` was automatically bound to location 0; I did not call `glBindAttribLocation`, but instead relied on the originally bounded values during linking.  Apparently in GL compatibility context (2.1 in OS X), glDrawElements may not draw anything if whatever attribute is bounds at location 0 is not 'enabled', i.e. you call `glEnableVertexAttribArray` on it.

So, when I explicitly bind position to 0 and color to 1, I can call glVertexAttrib*() on the color attribute and it will draw just fine in both OS X (legacy) and ES 2.

Answer (score 1):

This issue persists in Apple's GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE on my iMac running OS X 10.1 with an NVidia GeForce GTX 680MX.

The easiest solution was to do as rich.e suggested and explicitly bind position to 0. In my shaders position is referred to as `vPosition`, and I use a function from a textbook, InitShader, to load, compile and link shaders. Since positions may be re-bound on link, modifying this code:

```
GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader.glsl", "fshader.glsl" );
glUseProgram( program );
```

to this:

```
GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader.glsl", "fshader.glsl" );
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vPosition");
glLinkProgram(program);
glUseProgram( program );
```

solved my problem.